# macos Catalina - terminal shell will not start

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Logging in to my user account on my Mac this morning as usual, and the terminal won't start. I get a 1 line message giving last login details but it doesn't go any further. This user account is a specific one I use for dev work; my 'regular' account on the same machine opens terminal fine. And last time I was logged in to this account it was working fine - I use terminal (iTerm2 in fact) on a regular basis throughout my working day. zsh shell, macOS Catalina 10.15.7

No changes to anything as far as I'm aware since it was last working. I have tried stripping everything out of my .zshrc file (until it is as bald as my working one on my working user account) but it makes no difference.

Trying to run a script file that I would normally run in a terminal results in exactly the same thing - a one-line terminal window, hung.

I've tried looking in console for clues, but it's so thick with irrelevant messages and I don't know what to filter for.

Where do I start looking for the cause and fix?

UPDATE: here's the console log filtered for the terminal process:

```
default 10:10:20.016369+0100    Terminal    FRONTLOGGING: version 1
default 10:10:20.016392+0100    Terminal    Registering, pid=1376
default 2020-10-.01786212 10:10:20+0100 Terminal    CHECKIN: pid=1376
default 10:10:20.026638+0100    Terminal    CHECKEDIN: pid=1376 asn=0x0-0x7c07c foreground=1
default 10:10:20.051476+0100    Terminal    Registered, pid=1376 ASN=0x0,0x7c07c
default 10:10:20.051651+0100    Terminal    Registered, pid=1376 cgConnectionID=25127
default 10:10:20.053427+0100    Terminal    BringForward: pid=1376 asn=0x0-0x7c07c bringForward=1 foreground=1 uiElement=0 launchedByLS=1 modifiersCount=1 allDisabled=0
default 10:10:20.053556+0100    Terminal    BringFrontModifier: pid=1376 asn=0x0-0x7c07c Modifier 0 hideAfter=0 hideOthers=0 dontMakeFrontmost=0 mouseDown=0/0 seed=0/0
default 10:10:20.053925+0100    Terminal    BringForward: pid=1376 asn=0x0-0x7c07c
default 10:10:20.054195+0100    Terminal    SetFrontProcess: asn=0x0-0x7c07c options=0
default 10:10:20.061427+0100    Terminal    Current system appearance, (HLTB: 1), (SLS: 0)
default 10:10:20.066051+0100    Terminal    Post-registration system appearance: (HLTB: 1)
default 10:10:20.114454+0100    Terminal    NSApp cache appearance:
-NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance: 0
-appearance: (null)
-effectiveAppearance: <NSCompositeAppearance: 0x60000251d280
 (
    "<NSAquaAppearance: 0x60000250f080>",
    "<NSSystemAppearance: 0x60000250f100>"
)>
default 10:10:20.172149+0100    Terminal    Registering for test daemon availability notify post.
default 10:10:20.172287+0100    Terminal    notify_get_state check indicated test daemon not ready.
default 10:10:20.216376+0100    Terminal    SignalReady: pid=1376 asn=0x0-0x7c07c
default 10:10:20.217597+0100    Terminal    SIGNAL: pid=1376 asn=0x0x-0x508028
default 10:10:30.189116+0100    Terminal    LSExceptions shared instance invalidated for timeout.
```

It appears that the LSExceptions issue is irrelevant - my working account shows the same thing. The contrast between the two is that when it's working, after the SIGNAL message (penultimate line above) something called PKDiscoveryDriver kicks in, which is absent here.

Answer (score 1):

OK, eventually I got to the bottom of this. Was sure it had to be something to do with the shell itself since it wasn't even getting to a prompt.

I had to go to advanced options in users and groups, and change my shell back to the standard zsh one. Previously I had it pointing to a homebrew version of zsh, specific to this account. For some reason that seems to have stopped working, and even trying brew upgrade etc doesn't fix it. Switching back to the stock zsh shell seems to have done the trick.